# Selector to remove first X elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list with the following markup:

```
<div id="myList">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
            //...
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
            //...
    </div>

    //...

</div>
```

If I want to remove the first X (X is a specific number) childs of the list, which selector can I use in the following statement:

```
$("#myList").remove("???");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using [slice()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice):

```
$("#myList > div").slice(0,n).remove();
```

Where n is the amount of items you want to remove. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YTBqe/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:lt()` selector:

```
$('#myList > div:lt(x)').remove();
```

Where x is the amount of items you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

You can slice and remove. See below,

```
$('#myList').children().slice(0, X).remove();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NUYcY/1/